# Appearance icon has disappeared from system settings menu

Tags: 12.10, appearance, system-settings

I go to system settings and appearance is gone. I tried searching it in the dash and it is not there. When I right click the desktop and select "Change background" the system settings window opens. I tried going to the ubuntu software center and installing it from there it installed and popped up on my launcher. I tried clicking it and it opened up the system settings menu and appearance was still not there. I unlocked it from my launcher and searched for it in the dash and it was not there. Please help.

Comment: What happens when you try `sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center`?

Comment: $ sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree
       
Reading state information... Done

gnome-control-center is already the newest version.

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sorry about this I figured it out.

I was missing the packages:

```
gnome-control-center-signon
```

and

```
gnome-control-center-unity
```

When I installed them appearances reappeared.

Comment: i had this same problem after installing gnome 3, looks like gnome 3 had uninstalled gnome-control-center-unity

Comment: appearance is back now

Comment: Was having this problem on 16.04.1 running Unity. Solved it with 

sudo apt-get install unity-control-center && sudo apt-get install unity-control-center-signon

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after removing iBus.  Removing ibus solved the problem of the changing keyboard language settings but also removed icons from my system settings menu. So I reinstalled ibus and now I'm back to square one with changing keyboard languages, but with a complete settings menu :-)