# System settings is missing

Tags: 13.04, system-settings

System settings is missing. I tried reinstall it as it mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/251070/appearance-icon-has-disappeared-from-system-settings-menu), but it seems to be installed and deactivated. This problem occurred when I installed Elementary desktop environment and uninstalled it afterwards.

Comment: what's the error when you run `gnome-control-center` from terminal?

Comment: I get that it's not installed   
"The program 'gnome-control-center' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center"


When I try to install it I get :



"sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center  
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree         
Reading state information... Done  
gnome-control-center is already the newest version.  
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can try to reinstall `gnome-control-center` from terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-control-center
```

Comment: I made this far into the problem and solution and got the error:  `The following packages have unmet dependencies:` 
` gnome-control-center : Depends: gnome-settings-daemon (>= 3.9.91) but 3.8.6.1-0ubuntu11.2 is to be installed`

Comment: Still working in 17.10 :)

Comment: Still working on Ubuntu 20.04. Thank you, my friend.

Answer (score 5):

In case you install Gnome 3.12 on Ubuntu 14.04 via the gnome3-staging ppa you need to:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-settings-daemon-schemas
```

This will install the settings daemon correctly. There seems to be an issue with dependencies and correct upgrade paths.

Comment: Thanks, had been playing with Gnome 3.12 and could not figure where the settings had gone.

Answer (score 0):

After you do this, log out and back in, then go to (search your computer and online sources) top left type in (system settings) then drag the icon to your launch bar. That will put it back in the left launch bar also

Answer (score 0):

I know this is already late but it can still help someone.
This can happen when a library required to run gnome control center is missing, you can fix this by reinstalling or updating gnome.
I was able to fix this on Debian 10 (buster) running GNOME desktop environment. Open terminal and run

`sudo apt-get update` 
`sudo apt-get install --reinstall task-gnome-desktop`