# System Settings / Appearance

Tags: unity, settings, appearance

I upgraded the Ubuntu from 12.04 to 14.04 and I cannot find the "Appearance" icon in the system settings, beside some other settings.

May someone help me with it?

[image: pic]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Appearance icon has disappeared from system settings menu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/251070/appearance-icon-has-disappeared-from-system-settings-menu)

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the dash and start typing "system settings". Once you open system settings you should see this:

[image]

Comment: No. I can not see appearance. I comes out "display" and under it there is not the expected information/icons that I should found under "appearance".

Comment: Looks like your issue is a duplicate, try this solution: http://askubuntu.com/questions/251070/appearance-icon-has-disappeared-from-system-settings-menu